# Subprocess Popen not capturing wget --spider command result

Tags: python, subprocess, wget

My understanding of capturing the output of a subprocess command as a string was to set `stdout=sucprocess.PIPE` and use `command.communicate()` to capture `result, error`.

For example, typing the following:

```
command = subprocess.Popen(["nmcli", "con"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res, err = command.communicate()
```

produces no output to the terminal and stores all my connection information as a byte literal in the variable res. Simple.

It falls apart for me here though:

```
url = "http://torrent.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/trusty/release/desktop/xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent"
command = subprocess.Popen(["wget", "--spider", url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This prints the output of the command to the terminal, then pauses execution until a keystroke is input by user. Subsequently running `command.communicate()` returns an empty bytes literal, `b''`.

Particularly odd to me is the pause in execution as issuing the command in bash just prints the command result and directly returns to the prompt.

All my searches just find Q&A about how to capture subprocess results in general, not anything about certain commands having to be captured in a different manner or anything particular about wget and subprocess.

Additional note, I have been able to use the `wget` command with subprocess to download files (no `--spider` option) without issue.

Any help greatly appreciated, this one has me stumped.

Comment: Try `for line in iter(command.stdout.readline,""):print(line)`

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham - thanks for the suggestion, but it returns an infinite series of empty byte literals.

Comment: ok so you are using python3 it would be `b""` instead of `""`, what output are you expecting?

Comment: @ Padraic Cunningham - The output of the wget --spider command contains several lines verifying proper resolution of an url and the size of the file it points to. Issuing the command the way you specified still causes subprocess to print to the terminal. The print command prints nothing as subprocesses passes it an empty list as a result. I verified this by putting the command in a list comprehension.

Comment: added an answer, for some reason stderr is capturing the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stderr` is capturing the output so because you are not piping stderr you are seeing the output when you run the command and stdout is empty:

```
url = "http://torrent.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/trusty/release/desktop/xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent"
command = Popen(["wget", "--spider", url],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
out,err = command.communicate()

print("This is stdout: {}".format(out))
print("This is stderr: {}".format(err))
This is stdout: b''
This is stderr: b'Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.\n--2015-02-09 18:00:28--  http://torrent.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/trusty/release/desktop/xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent\nResolving torrent.ubuntu.com (torrent.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.95.21\nConnecting to torrent.ubuntu.com (torrent.ubuntu.com)|91.189.95.21|:80... connected.\nHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK\nLength: 37429 (37K) [application/x-bittorrent]\nRemote file exists.\n\n'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I feel pretty dumb.

Comment: @Jefe, don't worry about it, it is not obvious to think that it would be.

Answer (score 1):

I've never been asked anything by wget before, but some processes (e.g. ssh) do capture the terminal device (tty) directly to get a password, short-cutting the process pipe you've set up.

To automate cases like this, you need to fake a terminal instead of a normal pipe. There are recipes out there using termios and stuff, but my suggestion would be to use the module "pexpect" which is written to do exactly that.

Comment: Seems like a prime suspect. I'll have to give this a shot.